# Буза, бузить и бузотер

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Буза - это просяное пиво, слабоалкогольный напиток, изобретенный скифами. Бузить - шуметь, скандалить. И вот мне интересно, что первично: пиво или поведение? А еще - почему скандалиста называют "бузотер"? Не представляю себе, как можно бузу тереть))))
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сначала пиво, потом поведение)))

Answer (score 2):

Слово «буза»  в значении пьянящий напиток в тюркских языках известно с глубокой древности, также на Руси западные путешественники в 15 веке упоминают род пива, называемый "босса" . У Лермонтова в повести "Бэла": Черкесы как напьются бузы на свадьбе  или на похоронах, так и пошла рубка".

Переносное значение у слова «буза»  является поздним и отмечается в первой половине 20 века, например: «Никаких слухов, никакой бузы» (1925 год).

Также интересно появления выражения «тереть бузу» в значении скандалить: «Приедем, дома бузу затрем… даешь, мол, хорошие столовые» . Отсюда и бузотер  – скандалист.

Прямое значение этого выражения  –  обозначение начальной стадии приготовления бузы из смешанных круп: гречневых, овсяных, пшенных.

Answer (score 0):

Буза Русская - народная традиция рукопашного боя. Народная традиция русского рукопашного боя стала основой для создания в нашем отечестве в советское время, одной из лучших в мире, системы ближнего боя.

Comment: А источник этого?

Comment: С каких пор традиция? В советское время... Это когда? Боец по определению — бузотёр?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить на вопрос о происхождении слова  <<**БУЗА**>> , давайте сначала разберёмся , что оно означает , и с чем связано . Не знаю , кто как , но лично я впервые столкнулся с этим словом в далёкие 60-е , когда на советский экран вышел фильм **"Республика ШКИД"** , Ленфильм , 1966 г . В то время это был детский кино-хит . Тогда же была переиздана и книга-повесть Г.Белых , Л.Пантелеев **"Республика ШКИД"** (1927 г.) , - в то время это был школьный бестселлер . Авторы повести - бывшие воспитанники ленинградского детдома , школы им Достоевского (сокр.ШКИД) рассказывали о жизни трудновоспитуемых беспризорников , в 20-е годы получивших , благодаря советской власти , путёвку в жизнь . **Причём автор книги Л. Пантелеев был и сценаристом одноимённого фильма .** Вот там , и в книге и в фильме ,   присутствует эпизод **БУЗЫ** - детской войны детдомовцев с халдеями-педагогами . **БУЗА** эта выражалась в разных формах . Обратим вниманием на один из способов той БУЗЫ , которым срывались уроки (нам это ещё понадобиться) , - я цитирую по тексту повести :

> Лишь только педагог входил в класс и приступал к уроку, в классе раздавалось тихое гудение, которое постепенно росло и переходило в рев.
>
> Преимущество этого метода борьбы состояло в том, что нельзя было никого уличить.
>   Ребята сидели смирно, сжав губы, и через нос мычали.
>   Кто мычит, – обнаружить невозможно. Стоит педагогу подойти к одному, тот сразу замолкает и сидит, поджав губы, педагог отходит – мычание раздается снова.
>
> Говорить невозможно.
>
> Уроки срывались один за другим.

То же самое гудение-мычание с закрытым ртом во время урока показано и в фильме . =========================================================================== Таким образом , следует понимать , что <<**БУЗА**>> это **шумное , хулиганское неповиновение** . ===========================================================================  А теперь откроем "**Полный церковно-славянский словарь**" магистра **Гр. Дьяченко** на стр.61 /интернет.ссылка [ПЦСС стр.61](http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0061.htm)/ и увидим там слово <<**БУКА**>> , а следом слово <<**БОѴКАРИ**>> - *с ижицей* . Значения : **БУКА** = **шум , смятение** , *а также связь с* **жужжанием** и **мычанием** ; **БОѴКАРИ** = **бунт** . См. скриншот ниже . /// У Вл. Высоцкого : песня "Почему аборигены съели Кука ?" - "*... Есть вариант , что ихний вождь , большая БУКА , / Кричал , что очень вкусный кок на судне Кука ! / Ошибка вышла ...*" . /// При этом составитель ПЦСС считает , что слово <<**БУКА**>> суть   "*не заимствованно*" ; с чем , однако , как увидим далее , можно не согласиться .   ======================================================================== [image: ПЦСС стр.61 БУКА][image: ПЫСС стр.61 БУКА БОVКАРИ] ========================================================================== Теперь вопрос : почему в <<**БУКА**>> - **У** , а в <<БОѴКАРИ>> - **ОѴ** /*он-ижица*/ ? . Ответ : греческий алфавит не содержит буквы для звука **У** и этот звук обозначается буквосочетанием **ου** /*омикрон-ипсилон*/ , которое соответствует латинскому **OU** ; то есть в <<**Б**-**ОѴ**-**КАРИ**>> путаница греческого и латыни . Мы уже сталкивались с таким буквосочетанием *он-ижица* в моём ответе про "олуха" - <<**ВОЛОѴХЪ**>> =**пастух** , и отсюда <<**ОЛУХЪ**>> Но , в то же время , греческий алфавит не содержит и буквы для звука **Ц** , и можно предположить , что в <<**БУКА**>> и  в <<**БОѴКАРИЙ**>> присутствует замена , - **К** вместо латинской **C** . Отметим , что по фонетике латыни **C** чаще всего озвучивается , как **Ц** , но возможна и озвучка , как **К** . =========================================================================== А теперь откроем "**Большой латинско-русский словарь**" /интернет.ссылка [БЛРС алфавитный указатель](http://linguaeterna.com/vocabula/list.php?letter=B)/ и найдём в нём слово <<**BUCCA**>> . Отметим значнения этого слова : **ЩЕКА** , причём ,  *надутая* ; **ГОРЛАН** , *о трубаче* ; **КРИКУН**  .  //// **Эти значения вполне подходят как к** <<**БУКА**>> **, так и к** <<**БУЗА**>> **.**  Скриншот см. ниже . =========================================================================== [image: БЛРС BUCCA] =========================================================================== Я не случайно привёл выдержку из **"Республики ШКИД"** , где детдомовская  **БУЗА** , в одной из форм , выражалась **в гудении-мычании с закрытым ртом** на уроках , - *попробуйте сами погудеть и помычать не открывая рот : лучше всего это получается путём надувания щеки , - попробуйте !* ...  И тут должно быть вполне понятно , что  *грекоподражающий* церковно-славянский языкотворец заменил латинское **C**  на **К** : БУ-**К**-**К**-А  , а в окончательной редакции закрепилось **БУКА** (с одной **К**) . Теперь осталось выяснить , каким образом латинское -**CC**- перешло в **З** . Ну это тоже обнаруживается  экспериментальным путём : *попробуйте сами произнести сдвоенное* **Ц** *слитно* , - **ЦЦ**- , *и сами убедитесь , что послышится нечто вроде* **З** . *Попробуйте !* ... =========================================================================== С таким переходом **Ц** и -**ЦЦ**- в **З** мы сталкиваемся также и в слове <<**БУЗИНА**>> , которое , несмотря на похожесть , с <<**БУЗА**>>  этимологического родства не имеет . Известно , что из веток бузины ещё в Древней Греции делали свирели-дудочки (см. по Виккипедии "Свирель") . /// Лично у меня с юных лет засели в голове начальные строки детского стихотворения : "*Кто умеет делать дудочку ? / Я умею делать дудочку ! / Срежу ветку бузины / Вот такой-такой длины ...*" ./// Латинское слово <<**BUCINA**>> в переводе означает  **труба** , **рог** , **сигнальный горн** (*пастуший , охотничий и проч.*) . То же самое и в итальянском <<**BUCCINA**>> , тут сдвоенное -**CC**/-**ЦЦ** , в переводе - **трубы** . =========================================================================  "Латынь из моды вышла ныне ..." , писал поэт в "Евгении Онегине" . Ну , это , когда как . В Российской Империи латынь то выходила из моды , то потом снова  в моду входила . Старорусский языкотворец имел пристрастие к греческому и латинское <<**BUCCA**>> воспроизвёл в форме <<**БУКА**>> , а более современный творец русского сленга , имевший знакомство с латынью ,  переиначил это <<**BUCA**>> в <<**БУЗА**>> по типу -**ЦЦ**- = **З** . =========================================================================== Теперь о <<БУЗОТЁР>> . Разумеется , БУЗУ никто не ТРЁТ . Здесь суффиксное окончание по типу : ВОЛОН-ТЁР , ГЕЛИКОП-ТЕР (=вертолёт) , ПАРЛАМЕН-ТЁР , ГАНГС-ТЕР и др .